# why excel file downloaded using java servlet and apache POI library complains about file format or extension?

Tags: java, excel, servlets, apache-poi

I have created a java servlet class. The `getEmployeeExperienceInExcel()` method of this servlet creates the excel file where employee details should be printed `(employee details are featched from database).` Below is the code I have written in `getEmployeeExperienceInExcel()` method to create a excel file.

```
public void getEmployeeExperienceInExcel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Date startDate,
        Date endDate, String org1, String org2, String org3) throws IOException {

    ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"employeeDetails.xlsx\"");

    String[] titles = { "First name", "last name", "employee number", "Experience" };

    List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    //Get all emplyees of the organization
    employeeList = getEmployee(org1, org2, org3, startDate, endDate);

    try {

        Date startDateForString = startDate;
        Date endDateForString = endDate;

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        String startDateInString = df.format(startDateForString);
        String endDateInString = df.format(endDateForString);

        // Creating a Workbook
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

        // Creating spreadsheet 
        XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet(" employeeDetails");

        // For creating font bold
        CellStyle boldStyleForCell = workbook.createCellStyle();
        Font font = workbook.createFont();// Create font
        font.setBold(true);// Make font bold
        boldStyleForCell.setFont(font);

        // Setting for excel cell to accept date of the format dd.MM.yyyy
        CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        CellStyle dateCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        dateCellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"));

        // Setting column name at the top of excel file

        XSSFRow headerRow = spreadsheet.createRow(6);

        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellStyle(boldStyleForCell);
            cell.setCellValue(titles[i]);
        }

        // In excel row number 1 print info
        XSSFRow excelRow1 = spreadsheet.createRow(1);
        Cell cellForReportInfo = excelRow1.createCell(0);
        cellForReportInfo.setCellStyle(boldStyleForCell);
        cellForReportInfo.setCellValue("Employee Information");

        // In row number 3 print info
        XSSFRow excelRow3 = spreadsheet.createRow(3);
        excelRow3.createCell(0).setCellValue("Organization");
        excelRow3.createCell(1).setCellValue("Account");

        // In row number 4 print info
        XSSFRow excelRow4 = spreadsheet.createRow(4);
        excelRow4.createCell(0).setCellValue("Years");
        Cell cellForDatesRange = excelRow4.createCell(1);
        cellForDatesRange.setCellValue(startDateInString + " - " + endDateInString);

        //Loop through all the employee and print info in excel file
        int rowCount = 7;
        for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
            XSSFRow excelRow7 = spreadsheet.createRow(rowCount++);
            excelRow7 = spreadsheet.createRow(rowCount++);
            excelRow7.createCell(0).setCellValue(employee.getFirstname());
            excelRow7.createCell(1).setCellValue(employee.getLastname());
            excelRow7.createCell(2).setCellValue(employee.getEmployeeNumber());

            Cell cellForFulFillDate = excelRow7.createCell(3);
            cellForFulFillDate.setCellValue(employee.getFulfill_date());
            cellForFulFillDate.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);

        }


        workbook.write(os);
        workbook.close();
        os.flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I can sucessfully download the excel file from above code, but when I try to open the excel file, excel throws below error message: Excel cannot open the file `'employeeDetails.xlsx'` because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

**Is there anything I am missing/wrong in my code? Could somebody help me with this?**

> NOTE: I have excel 2013 in my machine which I think should support
>   xlsx file.

The picture shows the error message that excel throws when I try to open the file:

[image]

And if I open the excel file anyway with "Ok" option in above picture, I get all corrupted text. Please check below picture.

[excel file with corrupted text/data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06vzj.png)

Comment: Could you please add the complete error message to your question? Excel 2013 definitely supports xlsx files.

Comment: Hello @deHaar, I have added picture of error message. Please have a look.

Comment: That is a result of a not correctly or completely written file. You can try to `flush()` **and** `close()` the output stream before closing the workbook (that is how it works in my code).

Comment: Please try `response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");` for `*.xlsx`.

Comment: @Saroj could you please try content type as  `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: @deHaar, as you suggested, I flush() and close() output stream before closing the workbook, but still I got the same issue. Is there any other suggestions that can be helpful?

Comment: @Saroj have you tried with above suggestions ?

Comment: Try @Saroj 's suggestion and if it does not work, go the hard way: Write the workbook directly from the stream, flush, close and then re-open it via `File` or `FileInputStream`. Then apply your changes and write, flush, close again...

Comment: gks and Axel Richter. I tried your suggestion as well but doesn't work :(

Comment: @Saroj could you please try to use format as  `.xls` instead of `xlsx` . may i know version of Apache POI library ?

Comment: @deHaar, would you please explain a bit in a detail (may be with code) because I didn't catch clearly.

Comment: @gks, Even I changed the extension to .xls and didn't help !!

Comment: You are receiving an output stream by `ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();` Can you write an xlsx file only using that stream? Maybe you have to convert it to a `FileOutputStream` first. To chronologically exclude error causes, I would check that first. If it works, then keep writing the file, but re-open it afterwards, apply your changes and write it again.

Comment: @deHaar Yes I can download excel file with ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream(); with proper excel file and extension. Only issue is excel throws that error message each time when I tried to open.

Comment: Then it is not properly written. The file gets corrupted during being written. What I meant is: Are you able to just store the file received from the output stream **and** is it then openable without the error? If not, the cause will be the stream, most likely.

Comment: @deHaar.. Yes the downloaded file gets saved automatically in Downloads folder (window machine) with the name and extension that I have in response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"employeeDetails.xlsx\"");

Comment: So the error only occurs after you have written changes to it?

Comment: @deHaar... Yes it even writes the text/data in excel and if I try to open the excel file eventhough it throws error message, then I get corrupted text/data in file. I have added picture in question please have a look.

Comment: Wow, that looks like some binary stream written to a text file... Is it in this state after the download or / and after you have written to it? Could be caused by different charsets, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @deHaar, yes these binary stream are in the downloaded excel file. The data which are to be written in excel file contains scandinavian characters like ä, ö ...Could it be the reason? Do you know how can I have correct charset?